# Which recommender system approach allows for inclusion of user profile?

Tags: recommender-system

I wanted to enhance a recommendation engine with information relying not only on past purchases or ratings but also on behavioral and demographical variables like **sex, age, location, service usage frequency or hours**. This information may be sparse (**e.g. the user may not have provided me with his age**).

Can you suggest an approach that would allow for it?

---

#### My first approach:

After screening the general approaches to recommender systems, I think the one that is able to implement my idea is custom(?) **item-based collaborative filtering**.

To be more precise: I would include user profile information in the same way item ratings are introduced, probably with two alterations to raw data:

> 1. Normalize scale to be compliant with the rating scale.
> 2. Add a parameter in my algorithm that would put a weight (e.g. 20% or 50%) on user profile rows, as there may be 10 user-profile
>    variables and a million product items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [matrix/tensor factorization](https://www.google.si/search?q=matrix%20factorization%20recommender%20systems) methods and [data fusion](http://helikoid.si/bc215/bc2-handouts.pdf).

Comment: It may not be obvious to readers how tensor factorization facilitates the accommodation of users profiles. It would be good if you explained.

Comment: As far as I understand, you can have anything you want (i.e. user's age) on the third (fourth etc.) dimension. I really have no in-depth knowledge or understanding of the subject, so I'd rather just stay with throwing the bone. :)

Comment: That requires some deeper understanding, but there is a direct statement that these methods can solve my problem, so it appears it is exactly what I have been looking for. Thank you. 

More examples of other techniques for incorporation of user profile information + assessment of my approach are still welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

For the problem like this, you should try item-based collaborative filtering. There is a book named "The Ancient Art of Numerati (A guide to data mining)", a whole chapter on this book is based on item based collaborative filtering with a very good examples and also some coding samples of python for implementation. I suggest you do read this.

Comment: The book you are refering to (http://guidetodatamining.com/assets/guideChapters/DataMining-ch3.pdf) is actually a nice summary for basics of recommender systems. However, it does not contain an answer to my question.

Comment: Answer of your question is item based collaborative filtering.

Comment: Does it mean you suggest the approach I have outlined within the question?